# PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST was undefined at Openshift

Tags: python, postgresql, openshift

For the Python 3.3 cartridge and PostgreSQL 9.2 on Openshift.

When I ssh into the Openshift app I can see the content of the OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST:

```
echo $OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT
5432
```

However for the wsgi script the env vars are not passed - see the part from the python.log:

```
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_CRON_DIR was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PASSWORD was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_SOCKET was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable PGUSER was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_IDENT was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable PGDATABASE was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PID was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DIR was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ELEMENT was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_PATH_ELEMENT was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable PGHOST was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_CRON_IDENT was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_VERSION was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable PGDATA was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [warn] PassEnv variable OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_LOG_DIR was undefined
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Jan 15 16:27:33 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/3.3.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

The restart of the app in the application console did not help.
Neither restart of the python cartridge.

Please advice how to  propagate env vars to the wsgi script.

Comment: Have you tried stopping & starting (not restarting) your python application since you added postgresql?  Since it's running inside of apache as an wsgi application it may take a stop/start to see the env variables correctly.

Comment: yes, I tried. Both - python cartidge only (with gear restart --cart python) and the whole app (with rhc restart). Apologies - I did restart only. With stop / start it works now.

Comment: The script is executed by Apache with the Apache account configuration. With a virtualhost you can change the user in the WSGIDaemonProcess directive. Anyway, It's up to the WSGI script to setup the environment variables by setting `os.environ`. e.g.: `os.environ["OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT"] = 5432`…

Comment: @corey112358 please post it as an answer. I will mark it as correct. (For future unfortunate users).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try stopping & starting (not restarting) your python application especially if you added postgresql after your application was created. Since it's running inside of apache as an wsgi application it may take a stop/start to see the env variables correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To buttress the answer from [@developercorey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2879327/developercorey)

> Try stopping & starting (not restarting) your python application...

The commands to do that according to the documentation 
[from here](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/common-rhc-commands.html) are:

```
$ rhc app-stop {instance}
```

or

```
$ rhc app-force-stop {instance}
```

and

```
rhc app-start {instance}
```

**Note:** *Change {instance} to your Openshift application name.*